# Chromedp don´t perform actions inside a loop in ActionFunc

Tags: go, web-scraping, automation

I have a slice containing a list of terms, and I want to search for each term in a certain search engine page, so I am doing this:

```
func risk(slice []string) chromedp.Tasks {

    return chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate("https://testpage"),
        chromedp.WaitVisible("#query_box", chromedp.ByID),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(context.Context, cdp.Executor) error {
            for _, element := range slice[2:] {
                fmt.Println(element)
                chromedp.SendKeys("#query_box", element, chromedp.ByID)
                chromedp.Click("#searchButton", chromedp.ByID),
            }
            return nil
        }),
    }
}
```

When calling this inside `main` as

```
err = c.Run(ctxt, risk(items))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Everything works until the `ActionFunc`. Whatever action I can add before the function (take screenshot, etc...) work without issues.

However, the actions inside `ActionFunc` don't get performed.

Is the reason the `return nil`? I wanted to return the set of tasks like I am doing outside the loop, but I couldn't find about how to do that inside a loop in the `ActionFunc`, since the return would always be the latest item rather than the full set... Returning `nil` was the only way to get the function to at least get started.

What is the correct way to perform this sort of loop operations inside a set of `chromedp.Tasks`?

Comment: `ActionFunc` describes an action, it doesn't run it. You need to call `.Do(context, executor)` on your internal actions. You should also check for errors returned by `Do` and return that. You can see how the existing actions build up from other actions. For example, the [Navigate](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/blob/master/nav.go#L12) action.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually missing the `Do`, as you say. I added them and now the actions are running fine. Feel free to add an answer if you want, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chromedp.ActionFunc` is used to build a custom action. The function you give it will be executed during the `Run` phase.

This means that your function needs to actually run the actions you are using inside. This is done by calling the `.Do` method on the action and passing it a `context.Context` and `cdp.Executor`.

As for errors, the function should return any error encountered while running. When calling `.Do` on your embedded actions, check the error and return it if non-nil.

Your code should look like:

```
func risk(slice []string) chromedp.Tasks {

    return chromedp.Tasks{
        // ... other actions ...
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(c context.Context, e cdp.Executor) error {
            for _, element := range slice[2:] {
                fmt.Println(element)
                err := chromedp.SendKeys("#query_box", element, chromedp.ByID).Do(c, e)
                if err != nil {
                  return err
                }
                err = chromedp.Click("#searchButton", chromedp.ByID).Do(c, e)
                if err != nil {
                  return err
                }
            }
            return nil
        }),
    }
}
```

**disclaimer**: I haven't tested this code, so there may be issues, but this should give you the general idea of defining vs executing an action, and properly returning errors.